# it is possible to send push notification from one android app to a different android app?

Tags: android

Just wanted to check if it is possible to send push notification from one andriod app to a different andriod app considering both the apps has different product id and browser keys. If its not possible then what is the work around other than picking up the message from SMS inbox and displaying it ? The purpose is to have a merchant facing app and a different consumer facing app for intraction. So if a merchant push messages it should come as notification in the consumer app.

Comment: Will you be the developer for both of those app?

Comment: Both apps should have their own mechanisms to check a common server with the common information that should be exchanged and then send a push notification to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to obtain registration ID from the application you want to send the push message to and to know the API key. Just like when you want to send push messages from a server.

However, if there is a server involved, it is better to use the server to send the messages instead. It won't need to deal with unstable network connection.